# bash shell auto forward

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

i want to create own shell program, just to collecting data from my Operating system Solaris 11 & 10 for issue hardening. thats why better I need shell program, just running result the config of Solaris

but I stuck when running this script on my "file.sh" , the script cant running to next step, and always error.
please help how to make this script running well, with much script mostly collect like bellow script

```
 logins -ox |\
awk -F: '( $1 != "root" && $8 != "LK" && $8 != "NL" && \
( $10 < 7 || $11 > 91 || $12 < 7 )) { print }'
```

Comment: You will need to provide your input. e.g. a part of the output of `logins -ox` which you expect to be printed (first replace sensitive information with fake data)

Comment: done, script above is right, but when we set for bash script, we should remove slash(\) because it means of enter, and must input manually type. so, the solution just remove it and make it just one line.